# Conditional Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

code1, code2 and Code3 are constant whereas code1quantity,code2quantity values are from screen

if i dont get value for quantity, then code also should not be added to the array

Condition 1:

```
var Code1  = 'xyz';
var Code2  = 'abc';
var Code3  = 'mno';

var Code1Quantity  = 1;
var Code2Quantity  = 2;
var Code3Quantity  = 3;

var data = {
       Codes :  [{'code':Code1,'Quantity':Code1Quantity},
                 {'code':Code2,'Quantity':Code2Quantity},
                 {'code':Code3,'Quantity':Code3Quantity}
               ]
             }
```

Condition 2 needs to be achieved:

```
var Code1  = 'xyz';
var Code2  = 'abc';
var Code3  = 'mno';

var Code1Quantity  = 1;
var Code2Quantity  = 0;
var Code3Quantity  = 1;

var data = {
       Codes :  [{'code':Code1,'Quantity':Code1Quantity},
                 {'code':Code3,'Quantity':Code3Quantity}
               ]
             }
```

if Code2Quantity  is zero we should not add the code2 too, as the code quantity values are chosen from the screen, it may or may not have values

how it can be achieved?

Comment: how is json `data` created?

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: @JordiCastilla have updated the question

Comment: Are you creating `data` as an object literal or pragmatically `push`'ing data into `codes`?

Comment: you edited it, but IMO not _updated_, not even answered my question....

Comment: @JordiCastilla will pass the var data to the ajax post

Comment: Where does `Code1` `Code2` ... and `Code1Quantity` `Code2Quantity` variables come from ?

Comment: code1 and code2 are constant whereas code1quantity from screen

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian What do you mean **from screen** ?

Comment: @Weedoze from UserInterface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could collect all items in an array, build the array with the objects and filter by quantity.

```js
var Code1  = 'xyz',
    Code2  = 'abc',
    Code3  = 'mno',
    Code1Quantity  = 1,
    Code2Quantity  = 0,
    Code3Quantity  = 1,
    codes = [Code1, Code2, Code3],
    quantity = [Code1Quantity, Code2Quantity, Code3Quantity],
    data = { 
        Codes: codes.map(function (c, i) {
                return { Code: c, Quantity: quantity[i] };
            }).filter(function (o) {
                return o.Quantity;
            })
    };

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can treat array with filter function like below

```
var data = {
    Codes :  [{'code':Code1,'Quantity':Code1Quantity},
        {'code':Code2,'Quantity':Code2Quantity},
        {'code':Code3,'Quantity':Code3Quantity}
    ].filter(code => code.Quantity > 0)
}
```

Comment: it is syntax for ES6 arrow function. You can use alternative `.filter(function(code) { return code.Quantity > 0})`